Call to rsconnect::deployApp failing
In "App.R", all I'm trying to do (in vain) is load config.yml.
ConfigFileName <- paste0(RSourceFolder, "config.yml")
if (file.exists(ConfigFileName))
{
  Config <- config::get(file = ConfigFileName)
} else
  stop("Config file not found")

The code runs fine locally, I hit the issue when it's deployed on ShinyApps.io because config.yml file does not exist on ShinyApps.io.
Similar to loading the .yml in "App.R", I also need to source("RRUtils.R") in "App.R".
I can't get "config.yml" to upload from my PC to ShinyApps.io, in the same "folder" as App.R.
I have hit a brick wall writing the code to deploy my app to ShinyApps.io.
I need to upload the three files "App.R", "config.yml" and "RRUtils.R" to ShinyApps.io.
I have written this in a separate R script:
rsconnect::setAccountInfo(
  name='richardrogers',
  token='***',
  secret='***')

RSourceFolder <- "F:/Data/Dropbox/#1 - CC/R/"
CCTestAppDir <- paste0(RSourceFolder, "CCTest")

rsconnect::deployApp(
  account = 'richardrogers', 
  appDir = CCTestAppDir,
  appFiles = c(
    "App.R", 
    "../config.yml", 
    "../RRUtils.R"
  ),
  appName = "CCTest1"
)

I am receiving different responses in the RStudio Console:
-- Preparing for deployment -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
v Re-deploying "config" using "server: shinyapps.io / username: richardrogers"
i Looking up application with id "12212216"...
v Found application <https://richardrogers.shinyapps.io/config/>
i Bundling 1 file: config.yml
v Created 1,567b bundle
i Uploading bundle...
v Uploaded bundle with id 8781989
-- Deploying to server ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Waiting for task: 1430083320
  error: Parsing manifest
## Begin Task Log #########################################################################################
## End Task Log ###########################################################################################
Error: Unhandled Exception: child_task=1430083321 child_task_status=failed: Application mode static not supported.
In addition: Warning message:
R graphics engine version 16 is not supported by this version of RStudio. The Plots tab will be disabled until a newer version of RStudio is installed. 

I used to see these in the RStudio Console:
# -- Preparing for deployment ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#   v Re-deploying "CCTest1" using "server: shinyapps.io / username: richardrogers"
# i Looking up application with id "12212041"...
# v Found application <https://richardrogers.shinyapps.io/CCTest1/>
#   i Bundling 3 files: App.R, ../config.yml, and ../RRUtils.R
# i Capturing R dependencies with renv
# v Found 89 dependencies
# v Created 51,277b bundle
# i Uploading bundle...
# v Uploaded bundle with id 8779052
# -- Deploying to server --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#   Waiting for task: 1429861769
# building: Building image: 10676194
# building: Fetching packages
# building: Building package: RPostgres
# building: Installing packages
# building: Installing files
# building: Pushing image: 10676194
# deploying: Starting instances
# terminating: Stopping old instances
# -- Deployment complete --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#   v Successfully deployed to <https://richardrogers.shinyapps.io/CCTest1/>

Only "App.R" is uploaded to ShinyApps.io.
As I see it, I have two options:

Read the yml from the same location as App.R on ShinyApps.io (ideal), so I need to upload the yml when deploying
Read the yml file from googledrive/dropbox/pastebin

Question 1: Why is the call to deployApp only uploading "App.R"? The files exist at the correct paths!
Not really pertinent, but you can see the app results here: https://richardrogers.shinyapps.io/CCTest1/

Now, I've noticed that "config" appears as an app in my "Control Panel" at ShinyApps.io. What is going on here?

What version of R Studio are you using?

I'm using RStudio 1.4.1106, and R 4.3.3. I found the solution: All three files "App.R", "config.yml", and "RRUtils.R" must be in the same folder for deployApp to work properly.

Good for you that you figured it out.
